# Variable-Coefficient Linear Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve the differential equation: $4y''-4xy'+y=e^{x/2}*(1-x^2)^{1/2}$ ?
I can not deal with the variable "$x$" at the second term !!

Comment: Have you made any progress/attempted anything so far?

Comment: No, i can not reach to the auxiliary (characteristic) equation !!

Comment: Have you studied variation of parameters/power reduction in class?

Comment: yes, i have studied it.

Comment: But, as i said, i can't find any solution for the auxiliary equation (which i don't know it) to use the power reduction to get the second solution and hence, use the variation of parameters!

Comment: Strike my previous comment, that $y$ spoils my reduction.

Answer (score 1):

**Just a hint**

First thing put $y=ze^{\frac{x}{2}}$ to eliminate the exponential.

the new equation is
$$4z''+4(1-x)z'+2(1-x)z=\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

You could look for a solution as a power series.

Comment: the solution containes the Kummer function,

Comment: Excuse me, i can't progress in my solution after reaching to $4z'' = (1-x^2)^{1/2}$ !

Comment: @user5894199 Sorry. I thought we could simplify. i'll  edit it.

Comment: I reach also to $8z' = arcsin{x} + (x/2) * (1-x^2)^{1/2}$